# Revisiting votes after a longer period

Tags: discussion, support

I'm both a regular up-voter (to encourage) and a regular down-voter (in an attempt to sort 'good' from 'not-so-good' on site), and admittingly not all of my votes are always fully justified, but "good" vs. "bad" puzzle is also to quite some extend subjective. When I vote on a puzzle this is often before seeing the answer and potential edits to improve the puzzle, so there is every chance that at a later point, I would juge a puzzle differntly.

Now my questions:

> #### Is re-evaluating your votes on puzzles a good thing?

I asume yes, but am still interested in opinions.

> #### What is the best way to 'find' puzzles *you* have voted on (up & down)?

Is there a good search-option to be used? I would like to see a list of puzzles **I have voted on**.
Or is there a way to *display* one's votes in the over-view list of questions? Or some other good trick?

Answer (score 5):

You can view the questions you have voted on by looking at your profile page.  Click on your user picture at the top of any PSE page, then click "Activity" under the Puzzling logo at the left, then click "votes" in the row of options under the 3 grey boxes labelled Reputation, Badges, and Impact.

Re-evaluation is never a bad thing, but note that your vote gets locked after one hour, unless the question is edited after you vote.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, that certainly helps. However, it only gives you a (chronological) list of *actions* where as I would like to see a (filtered) list of the current *situation*, instead - which could be further 'sorted' or 'restricited' like any search.

Comment: @BmyGuest I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.  What "situation" are you talking about?  I thought you wanted a list of all the questions you have up-/down-voted?

Comment: I possibly need to play with this a little more, but the list is a chronological list of votes (sorted by time of vote) and I can't do anything with it like sorting it by "popular votes" or "newst edit" etc. As said, I missed that feature and your posting helps a lot, but I would still prefer to see something within the regular "search".